# What results of FunctionMeromorphic are true?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Studying a new command of 12.2 `FunctionMeromorphic`, I try

```
FunctionMeromorphic[(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Abs[z]^2, z]
```

> `False`

```
FunctionMeromorphic[(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Abs[z]^2 // Simplify, z]
```

> `False`

```
FunctionMeromorphic[((Re[z] - I*Im[z])/
Abs[z]^2 /. {Re[z] -> (z + Conjugate[z])/2, 
Im[z] -> (z - Conjugate[z])/2, 
Abs[z] -> Sqrt[((z + Conjugate[z])/2)^2 + ((z - Conjugate[z])/2)^2]}) //FullSimplify, z]
```

> `False`

```
FunctionMeromorphic[(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Abs[z]^2 // FullSimplify, z]
```

> `True`

I suspect the latest result is not true. I am right, aren't I?

Comment: The last result is of course correct since the simplification gives `1/z`. The function is almost certainly based mostly on expression structure and will not implicitly simplify (or, if it does, might not attain a meromorphic equivalent when one exists).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thak you for your explanation of the wrong behavior of `FunctionMeromorphic`. Let me repeat my suggestion "`FunctionMeromorphic` and `FunctionAnalytic`  hardly handle `Re[z], Im[z]`, and `Conjugate[z]`. As a palliative measure, these commands would be able to return inputs with `Re[z], Im[z]`, and `Conjugate[z]` unevaluated".  Hope I am clear.

Comment: The downvoter: What is wrong with my question? Deep regard.

Comment: They are treating Re, Im et al as they were designed to do. (I'm not the downvoter. If anything, I might vote to close as "requiring expert explanation" since it's a design question.)

Answer (score 2):

The function `(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Abs[z]^2` is
$$
f(z) = {\bar z \over |z|^2} = {\bar z \over z\, \bar z}={1\over z}
$$
which is meromorphic (holomorphic over $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}$). Actually

```
(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Abs[z]^2 // FullSimplify
```

returns `1/z` and

```
FunctionMeromorphic[1/z, z]
```

returns `True`.

As a side note one would be tempted to apply `FullSimplify` to all functions before checking with `FunctionMeromorphic`, however this causes other errors. For example the function $z\mapsto \bar z/\bar z$ is defined with value $1$ over $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}$ and undefined at $z=0$ ; however

```
FunctionMeromorphic[(Re[z] - I*Im[z])/Conjugate[z] // FullSimplify, z]
```

incorrectly returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Concerning `FunctionMeromorphic[z/z // FullSimplify, z]`, the same produces `FunctionMeromorphic[z/z ,z]` since Mathematica automatically simplifies expressions.. In my question `FunctionMeromorphic[((Re[z] - I*Im[z])/
Abs[z]^2 /. {Re[z] -> (z + Conjugate[z])/2, 
Im[z] -> (z - Conjugate[z])/2, 
Abs[z] -> Sqrt[((z + Conjugate[z])/2)^2 + ((z - Conjugate[z])/2)^2]}) //FullSimplify, z]` is presented, where `FullSimpliy` does not work.

Comment: Your understanding  of a meromorphic funcion is not true:  `Exp[1/z]` is analytic for `z!=0`, but is not meromorphic (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) for the definition). Thank you again for your interest to the topic.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks, I made a few changes and gave another example where `FullSimplify` is not appropriate.

Comment: Yes, `FunctionMeromorphic` and `FunctionAnalytic` hardly deal with `Re[z], Im[z]`, and `Conjugate[z]`. As a palliative measure, these commands would be able to return inputs with `Re[z], Im[z]`, and `Conjugate[z]` unevaluated. However, `Re[z], Im[z]` and `Conjugate[z]` are used in important applications.