# One more incorrect result of FunctionMeromorphic and FunctionAnalytic

Tags: bugs, complex

Two years ago I submitted [a bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244190/what-results-of-functionmeromorphic-are-true) in `FunctionMeromorphic` (That bug still persists in 13.2.). Here is one more incorrect result in it and `FunctionAnalytic`.

```
FunctionMeromorphic[Sin[z]/(Exp[z] - 1) /. z -> Re[z] + I*Im[z], z]
```

> `False`

```
FunctionAnalytic[{Sin[z]/(Exp[z] - 1) /. z -> Re[z] + I*Im[z], Exp[z] != 1}, z]
```

> `False`

What is the reason of such an incorrect behavior?

PS. Even worse with two complex variables. For example,

```
FunctionMeromorphic[Sin[z] /. z -> x + I*y, {x, y}]
```

> `True`

, but

```
FunctionAnalytic[Sin[z] /. z -> x + I*y, {x, y}]
```

> `False`

As I understand it, the latter should be `True` too.

Comment: Wasn't the answer already presented in your previous question? `FunctionMeromorphic[z, z]` is `True` but `FunctionMeromorphic[Re[z] + I Im[z], z]` is `False` because neither `Re[z]` nor `Im[z]` is meromorphic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What results of FunctionMeromorphic are true?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244190/what-results-of-functionmeromorphic-are-true)

Comment: @Domen: "because neither Re[z] nor Im[z] is meromorphic" is not documented (see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionMeromorphic.html?q=FunctionMeromorphic).

Comment: @DanielLichtBlau: No, this does not answer my question "
What is the reason of such an incorrect behavior?". For example, `FunctionAnalytic[{Sin[z]/(Exp[z] - 1) /. z -> Re[z] + I*Im[z], 
  Exp[Re[z] + I*Im[z]] != 1}, z]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494, are you claiming that `Re[z]` is actually meromorphic, or that every single possible function should be documented? Clearly you can evaluate `FunctionMeromorphic[Re[z], z]` and see the result ...

Comment: @Domen: I wrote that your claim " because neither `Re[z]` nor `Im[z]` is meromorphic" is not documented. The documentation says nothing about the composition of meromorphic functions with other functions . The function `Re[z]+I*Im[z]` is a meromorphic (even an analytic)) function of  complex variable `z`.